# How to fix "Null" output for AFK Channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

I'm having a problem where when I launch my bot and run this command, it says "undefined" or "null" as the output. How do I fix this?

I've tried using the same method as I did for all the other options.

```
if (serv.verified == false) {
    var veri = "No.";
}
```

Where it checks for a boolean, string, or number. It just doesn't seem to work. It sets my variable at null or undefined.

```
if (serv.afkChannel == `null`) {
    var afk = "No AFK VC.";
}

if (serv.verified == true) {
    var veri = "Yes.";
} 

if (serv.verified == false) {
    var veri = "No.";
} 

        var myInfo2 = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${serv.name}'s guild info`)
        .addField(`AFK Channel`,`${afk}`,true)
        .addField(`AFK Timeout`,`${serv.afkTimeout}s`,true)
        .addField(`Channels`,`${serv.channels.size}`,true)
        .addField(`Creation of Guild`,`${serv.createdAt}`,true)
        .addField(`Default Notification`, defn,true)
```

Expected Result : It will say No AFK VC
Actual Result : It says undefined or null.

Comment: note to past self: use `var veri; serv.verified ? ... : ...`, that's some bad code. p.s. this errored because I checked serv.afkChannel against a string, not `null`, but `'null'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to check if there IS a channel.
Then, you want to set the variable `afk` as No AFK Channel.
And last, if there is an afk channel it would say said AFK Channel.

```
if (!serv.afkChannel)
    var afk = `No AFK Channel`
    else var afk = `${serv.afkChannel}`
```

The "!" basically makes the following code opposite.
The next code would give off a `the variable afk is already defined` error, but it's basically a "OR". If there is no AFK channel then, OR If there is an AFK channel, then.

All you need now is to find out how to get rid of the # if you want to. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will ever match the literal string `'null'` other than... well, `'null'`. Here's just a brief example:

```js
console.log(null == 'null');       // The identity operator (==) even does type
console.log(undefined == 'null');  // conversions and these aren't the same.

console.log(null == null);         // These are both true, because null is not a string.
console.log(undefined == null);    // <-- Watch out: this is only true using the twins.

console.log('null' == 'null');     // The only match is the string compared to itself.
```

[`Guild.afkChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=afkChannel) will be `undefined` if the channel isn't defined. Nothing should ever return a *string* `'null'`. That being said, when you compare `serv.afkChannel` to `` `null` ``, the boolean will never be true.  Since you don't have an `else` in the chain, `afk` won't get to be defined.

---

When declaring the `afk` variable, you can use the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (`||`) to replace your `if`/`else` statements and prevent your issue:

```js
var afk = serv.afkChannel || 'No AFK Channel';
```

If `serv.afkChannel` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the variable will be declared as `'No AFK Channel'` instead.